# Cypress conditional statement depending on whether the input field is disabled or not

Tags: conditional-statements, cypress

I have some input fields on a page. They can be disabled or not. So I need to type the text in this field just in case when it's not disabled. I try to do this way:

```js
          fillPickUpTown(pickUpTown: string) {
            cy.get(`[data-testid="pick-up-town"]`)
              .should('not.be.disabled')
              .then(() => {
                cy.get(`[data-testid="pick-up-town"]`).type(pickUpTown);
              });
          }
```

But I have failed test with error "Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '' not to be 'disabled'".
How can I type to this field just when it's not disabled and do nothing when it is?

Comment: Does the disable/enable input fields occur randomly? For testing, you should try to avoid conditional scenarios.

Comment: These input fields are always exist, but they disable/enable condition is random.

Comment: That's odd. The someone on your team should know how to get those always enable/disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery `:enabled` to check and implement If-Else.

```js
fillPickUpTown(pickUpTown: string) {
  cy.get(`[data-testid="pick-up-town"]`).then(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.is(":enabled")) {
      cy.get(`[data-testid="pick-up-town"]`).type(pickUpTown)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the should, this will only succeed for the one condition. Instead, test inside then()

```js
fillPickUpTown(pickUpTown: string) {
  cy.get(`[data-testid="pick-up-town"]`)
    .then($el => {
      if (!$el.is(':disabled')) {
         cy.wrap($el).type(pickUpTown);
      }
    });
  }
```